# php form post updates database and refreshes page but does not update data on the page after refresh

Tags: php, forms

I can't seem to find a working solution in stackoverflow. I wish to update the form values with the updated data that is submitted in the form post. The database updates but after the refresh, the values are still the same. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$user_id  = get_current_user_id();
$org_id = get_user_meta($user_id, '_org_id', true);
$orgs = $wpdb->get_results("select * from wp_organization");
$user_org = null;

foreach($orgs as $struct) {
    if ($org_id == $struct->id) {
        $user_org = $struct;
        break;
    }
}
?>
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect("address", "login", 'password');
$db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'databasename');
    
if(isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $id = $org_id;
    
    $query = "UPDATE `wp_organization` SET         
        name = '$_POST[org_name]',
        shortname = '$_POST[shortname]',
        industry = '$_POST[industry]',
        description = '$_POST[description]'
        where id = $id ";
        
    $query_run = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}
}
?>
<!-- organization info form -->
<form class="py-4 col-md-6 mx-auto" method="post" action="">
    <h2 class="mb-3 text-center">Organization Information</h2>
    <label class="form-label">Name</label>
    <input type="text" required name="org_name" value="<?php echo $user_org-> name; ?>" 
        class="form-control mb-3" />
    <label class="form-label">Industry</label>
    <input type="text" name="industry" value="<?php echo $user_org-> industry; ?>" class="form-control mb-3" />
    <label class="form-label">Short name (4 characters)</label>
    <input type="text" name="shortname" required maxlength="4" value="<?php echo $user_org-> shortname; ?>" class="form-control mb-3" />
    <label class="form-label">Description</label>
    <textarea class="form-control mb-3" name="description" rows="5" cols="50"><?php echo trim(stripslashes($user_org-> description)); ?></textarea>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value='Update' class='btn btn-primary'> 
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your code is open to sql injection.

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-12/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: You seem to have an additional (hanging) `}`

Comment: ___Small point___ Whats the point of moving `$id = $org_id;` when you could just use `$org_id`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187)
You should always use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) 
in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenating user provided values into the query. Never trust ANY user input!

Comment: You use a where clause (`where id = $id`) in your update query, why don't you also use this in the select query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue that's causing old data to appear is that you are querying the database *before* you update it. The data displayed in the form is queried at the beginning of the page's execution, and later, if there's POST data, the database is updated. As a result, the data used to render the form is the old data, not the recently updated data. So in a very minimal way, you could simply switch the database query with the database update, and your data flow would work as intended.

However, there's several other issues with this code, most notably the SQL attack vulnerability. As a result, I'll address all of these issues in creating a complete and safe answer to this question.

---

1. **This is WordPress!**

Based on the presence of the `$wpdb` variable, as well as some of the table names, it appears that this is running as part of a WordPress site (or else alongside a WordPress install). As a result, you never need to make a any of the raw `mysqli_` calls. Instead, use the the methods [documented in the `$wpdb` class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/) which provide safe access to the database, and also will help ensure that any future changes to the WordPress database system don't break your code.

*Result*: Remove `mysqli_` methods.

2. **Watch out for unnecessary syntax**

There's several unnecessary bits of syntax which may have undesirable side effects. For instance, in the middle of the code you have

```
?>

<?php
```

What this code snippet actually does is insert a phantom bit of whitespace (in this case one literal newline character or `\n`) into the output of your page. If, for instance, you tried to set a header after this value you would get a difficult and mysterious error about output already having been sent. A good practice is that all of your business code lives in a single, contiguous block with just a single `<?php` at the top of your file.

In addition, your block that begins `if(isset($_POST['update']))` ends with an extra dangling closing bracket `}`.

Furthermore, inside your actual update section, the calls to the `$_POST` superglobal are not actual strings but raw tokens (such as `$_POST[shortname]`. I suspect you did this in order to take advantage of PHPs string interpolation. While this raw format does work for legacy reasons, it's much clearer and safer when interpolating a string like this to use something like `{$_POST['shortname']}` inside your string.

*Result*: Remove and clean up unnecessary syntax.

3. **SQL Injection! Oh My!**

The biggest scary bit of this code is wide open SQL injection attack that's enabled by passing un-trusted strings (in the form of the `$_POST` variables) to SQL. This has been the bane of thousands (if not millions) of websites. Anyone who can access your web page can pass any data they want into the form field, including SQL commands which can delete your database and compromise your server. Using raw SQL like this is wildly dangerous and should never be used. PHP includes a great library `PDO` for this, and there are many other options. However, as discussed above, since you're using WordPress, you can just use the `$wpdb`, which also has protections against SQL injection built in and provides further compatibility benefits with the WordPress database.

*Result*: Don't use raw SQL

4. **Update then Query (but Query first, too)**

The core problem that caused you to post the question was data not updating in the web page when a form is submitted until the next load. This is because you currently query the data from the database, then update the database after that. Since you use the result from the early query to display values in the web page, they're naturally not the new values.

I suspect you did this because you need the value of `$org_id` in order to create and query and as a result all your querying got clumped together. Nonetheless, this primary fetch of the `$org_id` needs to be in the beginning, but the rest of the query after the update.

*Result*: Fix query and update ordering.

5. **No data validation**

You blindly use the value of `$_POST` values, but these may not be set. In your example this will probably only lead to empty database values, but in other context this could be catastrophic. As mentioned above, anyone can request your page with any `$_POST` data they desire. Therefore, it's good practice to ensure that you provide default values in case the data sent to the server is missing some fields.

*Result*: Validate that all expected data is present.

---

A version of this code that updates the database before querying, so the data is correct on each page load and update, as well as incorporating the other fixes mentioned, might look something like this:

```
<?php

/// 1. Get the global WordPress Database Object
global $wpdb;

/// 2. Use WP helper functiosn to query the current user and org IDs
$user_id  = get_current_user_id();
$org_id = get_user_meta($user_id, '_org_id', true);

/// 3. Update the database if necessary
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    /// 3.i Prepare the variables

    // Note: In new versions of PHP, each of the isset ? : lines below could be replaced
    // with something like:
    //
    // $name = $_POST['org_name'] ?? "default org name";
    //
    // I've used the long version here, so you can really see what ?? means. You can also
    // put any value you want in the final string of these expressions, so for example
    //
    // $name = isset($_POST['org_name']) ? $_POST['org_name'] : "unknown";
    //
    // would provide the value "unknown" into the database. You could inline all of these
    // checks into the following call to $wpdb, but that would make for a very hard to read
    // line. Setting local variables to these values makes the code easier to follow.
    $name = isset($_POST['org_name']) ? $_POST['org_name'] : "";
    $short = isset($_POST['shortname']) ? $_POST['shortname'] : "";
    $ind = isset($_POST['industry']) ? $_POST['industry'] : "";
    $desc = isset($_POST['description']) ? $_POST['description'] : "";

    /// 3.ii Execute the query

    // Note: I assume that $org_id is an integer. If it's actually a string, then that
    // line in the query should read
    //
    // where id = %s
    $wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare("
        UPDATE `wp_organization` SET         
            name = %s,
            shortname = %s,
            industry = %s,
            description = %s
            where id = %d 
        ",
            $name, $short, $ind, $desc, $org_id
        )
    );

    // Alternatively to the raw $wpdb->query above, you could use the built in update method
    // of $wpdb, like so
    //
    // $wpdb->update('wp_organization', array(
    //      'name' => $name,
    //      'shortname' => $short,
    //      'industry' => $ind,
    //      'description' => $desc,
    //  ),
    //  array( 'id' => $org_id ),
    //  array('%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'),
    //  array('%d')
    // );
    //
    // This has the advantage that you don't have to write any SQL, but may be harder to understand
    // if you come back to maintain this code far in the future.
}

/// 4. Load the current value of $user_org, this will reflect any database changes made above

$orgs = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM `wp_organization`");
$user_org = null;

foreach($orgs as $struct) {
    if ($org_id == $struct->id) {
        $user_org = $struct;
        break;
    }
}

/// 5. Render the form
?>
<!-- organization info form -->
<form class="py-4 col-md-6 mx-auto" method="post" action="">
    <h2 class="mb-3 text-center">Organization Information
    <label class="form-label">Name
    <input type="text" required name="org_name" value="<?php echo $user_org->name; ?>" class="form-control mb-3" />
    <label class="form-label">Industry
    <input type="text" name="industry" value="<?php echo $user_org->industry; ?>" class="form-control mb-3" />
    <label class="form-label">Short name (4 characters)
    <input type="text" name="shortname" required maxlength="4" value="<?php echo $user_org->shortname; ?>" class="form-control mb-3" />
    <label class="form-label">Description
    <textarea class="form-control mb-3" name="description" rows="5" cols="50"><?php echo trim(stripslashes($user_org->description)); ?>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
        <input type="submit" name="update" value='Update' class='btn btn-primary'>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: I also just noticed, in order to load `$user_org` you could use a SQL query with a WHERE clause (using `$wpdb->prepare`, of course!) to only select a single row from the database instead of loading the entire `wp_organization` table as you do now.